# Is it possible to use one Windows computer as a display/storage for another Windows computer?

Tags: windows, networking, display, display-driver

For my work, I have two Windows 7 laptops (both are Lenovo T440p). I would like to use one as an external monitor for the second.

I know I can use Synergy to share my keyboard/mouse on both, but it is not what I want.

What I want is to have, like what is possible [using some iMacs](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT3924), one laptop screen used as external screen for the other. Ideally, I would also like to access to this machine files ...

An dobviously, in the best case, that software would be free of use.

Comment: I'd also like to know a solution which is performant... the ones I tried yet are just slow like hell and working on the "second monitor" isn't fun. I tried VNC+virtual second monitor driver, AirDisplay and another one which name I don't remember...

Comment: There really is something broken in SuperUser : why is my question downvoted/asked for close for being offtopic ? On StackOverflow, I would have add a clear message telling me why, but here, ... nope. I'm becoming to be really fed up with Superuser ... which sounds more and more like "I'm too much a superuser to answer your question". Is this a rant ? YES.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers." There's your message, lol. Well, actually, try this question slighty rephrased on "Software Recommendations" SE

Comment: @DebugErr Always seems weird to me to go on one StackExchange site for general user advice, then another, as soon as it become evident that answer can be another software ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A commercial solution I've been using is [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/). Another solution might be [spacedesk](http://spacedesk.ph/) which I only have tried on android, but should work on PC as well.

Good luck.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: @DavidPostill The products are named MaxiVista & spacedesk and does whats requested in the question - what more info is needed? A phone number? There are search engines that would find the products **even** if the links change you know. Sorry if I sound rude, but I think it was a real strange down-vote...

Comment: It wasn't my downvote ... :/ Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.

Comment: @DavidPostill OK, sorry for "accusing" you, and thanks for the tip. However, I just wanted to help the asker with something I had a solution for, without spending my lunch hour reading "rules". ;)

Comment: MaxiVista still doesn't work on Win8 afaik

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a way to connect your laptop to your other computer and use Window's built in software and use a Ethernet cable to access the hard drive.